# wkhtmltopdf - Spaces in URL

Tags: php, url, wkhtmltopdf, url-encoding, wkhtmltoimage

When using wkhtmltopdf I am unable to generate images when the URL contains a `%20`.

This isn't a problem when doing the same command locally via the command line.

Is there a way I can get this to work once it's online?

My code so far is:

```
<?php
$url = $_GET['url'];    // Website URL to Create Image
$name = $_GET['img'];   // Output Image Name
$command = "/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltoimage --no-images --crop-w 580";
$dir_img = "images/";     // Image files will be saved here
$ex_cmd = "$command $url " . $dir_img . $name;
$output = shell_exec($ex_cmd);
?>
```

This works fine unless there is a `%20` in the URL.

The page I need to screenshot *has* to have the `%20` in its URL so a function to remove it would not be a solution unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to escape your arguments, else you have a huge security hole in your code:

```
$url = escapeshellarg($_GET['url']);    // Website URL to Create Image
$name = escapeshellarg($_GET['img']);   // Output Image Name
$command = "/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltoimage --no-images --crop-w 580";
$dir_img = "images/";     // Image files will be saved here
$ex_cmd = "$command $url " . $dir_img . $name;
$output = shell_exec($ex_cmd);
```

This is just to get you started, you must also check `$_GET['url']` is url, and not eg `./config/database.php`, and `$_GET['img']` must be sanitized too.